# QR code - automatically redirect to URL

Tags: qr-code

its not a programming question but really need it. I am creating a QR code that should redirect user to specific URL - let's say "http://facebook.com". Scanning all QR codes created by different creators I have used behave in such a way that it shows the URL and ask me if I want to open it. Can i force to open it in a browser without showing an URL like on the picture?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okey, maybe someone will need it - you can't do it. It's all matter of app and most do like in the example - they let user decide if he or she wants to open this URL